# Is it possible to know if two polynomials will eventually have an equal value?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Is it possible to know that the polynomial $P_1(x_1) = P_2(x_2)$, if so how to find the value that they both equal?

Example: $$(13)^2 = 3(7)^2 + 3(7) + 1 = 169$$

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You can find the range of both polynomials easily enough, so then you just want to know if those ranges overlap?

Comment: I agree with lulu. Or do you mean integer values only? Then it becomes a more challenging task.

Comment: For example:  if a polynomial has odd degree then its range is all of $\mathbb R$.  That certainly simplifies things.

Comment: Sorry, any real or integer value

Comment: Well, if you allow real solutions then my comment on the range is all you need.

Comment: what would I have to do to find integer values?

Comment: @lulu: mh, what if the polynomial is $x^6+x^2+x$ for instance ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Oh, to be sure it can be hard to compute the absolute max and min of a polynomial, but I didn't get the impression that the OP was concerned about that.  (That said, I'm not at all sure what the OP is asking so I certainly might be missing the point entirely).

Comment: @kafeincognito  Can you clarify your question?  Does my observation regarding the ranges answer it?  For instance, if either (or both) of the polynomials has odd degree then the answer is always yes, the two have common values.  If both have even degree, more work is needed and if the degree is high then the computations might be difficult.  Is that helpful or is it missing the point?

Comment: @lulu: you said "find the range easily enough".

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Right, thinking we were talking about low degree.  I entirely agree that, in general, for even degree polynomials it's not easy to find the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you restrict to integers, this problem is quite arduous.

To illustrate, it took 158 years to prove that the only powers that differ by one are $3^2$ and $2^3$.

Also, the smallest solution of the "innocent"

$$x^2=109y^2+1$$ is known to be $x=158070671986249,y=15140424455100 $ (but $x^2=110y^2$ is solved by $x=21,y=2$). This tends to show that a brute-force search is hopeless.

AFAIK, there is no general method to tackle your problem. (Without the integer constraint, it is much more accessible.)